# Full stack asset pipeline for node, connect/express and broccoli

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, broccolijs

Firstly I must confess I am a noob at node. I've been using ASP.NET then PHP then Django before. Regardless, I've found node a breath of fresh air. This problem is also not strictly a node problem, but I need a node specific answer.

I have an express server and angular frontend. The server side templates are in swig and currently only serve for error pages and the index page. Mostly the angular templates will make up most of the front matter.

What I'm struggling with, if only only in deciding how to do it, is getting an efficient work flow for the asset pipeline. Server side templates must be able to inject the vanilla of assets during dev and testing. The same for client side templates during testing. Basically, running with express' static middleware should be an option without any configuration (maybe with some helper in server side assets). Thus git clone -> grunt -> viola.

However, during staging and production, I would like the server side files to stay vanilla. The template helpers may parse a manifest file indicating the cache busted links (CDN path maybe too). How to make the link from logical asset bundle name to production ready asset is a mystery for me, while keeping development transparent.

The client side templates may be minified, concatenated, injected or whatever, as it will be saved to some dist folder for uploading. It is important that the whole dependency tree (images, fonts, css, js) must be "exported" to the dist folder.

To deploy would then be: pushing the server side code to the server and running. And pushing client dist folder to some asset host (CDN, nginx, another node, maybe even connect static)

What my question(s) then actually is(are):

1. Is this workflow possible with tools such as broccoli/gulp/grunt alone?
   I've tried connect-assets but I don't want to conform to some predetermined folder path. Also the cli tool didn't produce the other static assets. Perhaps I don't understand the tool.
2. Am I following the correct approach?

I've added to a discussion on broccoli concerning the manifest file consumption:
https://github.com/mjackson/broccoli-rev/issues/1#issuecomment-49076249

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I use bower, so assets should be pulled from arbitrary (URLs too maybe) locations.

Comment: I think angular-fullstack is what you want. Even if you don't use it, it does almost all of what you're looking for. https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: I'm moving to angular-fullstack now... Saves me heaps of time trying to do it by myself. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) is what you want. Even if you don't use it, it does almost all of what you're looking for.

The only thing that it might be missing for you is deployment. It has built in support for Heroku and OpenShift deployment. You could use something like [grunt-ssh](https://github.com/andrewrjones/grunt-ssh) or [grunt-deploy](https://github.com/ZheFeng/grunt-deploy) for other deployment scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. It is 90% there. At least I now have an idea of how it should work. What I currently don't seem to find is prepending my CDN to the asset urls.

Comment: Check out [grunt-cdn](https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-cdn) or [grunt-cdnify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cdnify).